# A comparison between "Illustrate" and "exemplify"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I was wondering if you let me know in which one of the self-made sentences bellow, the bold part sounds redundant:

> Could you please exemplify it **with an example**?
>
> Could you please illustrate it **with an example**?

Based on the definitions in the most of the online dictionaries I visited , both of the verbs above mean to clarify or explain something using examples. But:

> 1) I'm not sure if they can always be freely exchanged.
>
> 2) Meanwhile, I don't know if they require the object "example" at all or it is implied by itself.

Comment: Based on the kinds of questions you've been asking about differences between words that seem synonymous, you would do well to consult Collins dictionary. I think it might help you.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exemplify  ....  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/illustrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Could you please illustrate it with an example?* is correct.

The dictionary says that [*Illustrate*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/illustrate) means **to make clear or intelligible**.
So you are asking the listener to *clarify* his point using an example.

[*Exemplify*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exemplify) means **to make an example out of**. Think of it as creating an example.

For example, if I say "Federer exemplifies grace and style in tennis" it would mean I am using Federer as an example of stylistic tennis players.

So, in my opinion, an example need not be exemplified.

Comment: That would be childish. I am just glad we were able to help. Thanks for adding the links.